# Android Loud speaker and call interception

Tags: android, sdk, telephony

I would like to know how to intercept incoming calls and activate loud speaker automatically. I read this class is used com.android.internal.telephony but I could not find propre documentation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for intercepting incoming calls

```
PhoneStateListener mListner = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                        // TODO
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                        // TODO
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            };
        };
```

Activate the loud speaker

```
AudioManager POAudioService = (AudioManager) POContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
POAudioService.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: In the above code, what is POContext? Is it a class you have created? I have tried similar code to turn on speaker using a BroadCastReceiver, but it does not work. Can you answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617381/turn-on-speakerphone-whenever-an-outgoing-call-is-made I have given all necessary permissions in Manifest file.

Comment: POContext is normal context..i have defined it as my own variable

Answer (score 2):

```
private TelephonyManager telManager;

//on create method
telManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if (telManager != null) {
            telManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }


PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

                onCall = true;


            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

                onCall = false;

            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {

                onCall = true;
                //activate your loud speaker


            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Required rights: 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"